# When is it possible to interpret composition as a natural transformation?

Tags: category-theory

First note that for any objects $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ in a category $C$, we can get a morphism $\bigcirc: Z^Y \times Y^X \rightarrow Z^X$ as following. We define $\bigcirc$ as $\lambda (eval_{Z^Y} \circ (id_{Z^Y} \times eval_{Y^X}))$. This is well defined because:
$$id_{Z^Y} \times eval_{Y^X}:Z^Y \times Y^X \times X \rightarrow Z^Y \times Y$$ $$eval_{Z^Y} \circ (id_{Z^Y} \times eval_{Y^X}) : Z^Y \times Y^X \times X \rightarrow Z$$
$$\lambda(eval_{Z^Y} \circ (id_{Z^Y} \times eval_{Y^X})) : Z^Y \times Y^X \rightarrow Z^X$$

(I haven't proved that this is associative or respects identities yet.)
Now, what is some way that you could interpret $\bigcirc$ as a natural transformation (in some category for which all exponential objects are defined.) My biggest trouble right now is how to interpret $Z^Y \times Y^X$ as a functor.

Or is there a different way to interpret composition as a natural transformation.

Comment: Why do you _want_ composition to be interpreted as a natural transformation?

Comment: $Z^Y \times Y^X$ and $Z^X$ can probably both be viewed as a functor from $C^3 \to C$, and then the morphism you have described is probably a natural transformation.  I do not have the time to work this out.  This question is better suited to math.stackexchange, however.

Comment: (1) I take it you mean a *cartesian closed* category. (2) Internal composition is an example of an extranatural transformation: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extranatural+transformation It's dinatural in $Y$.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Should I cross post it then?

Comment: I would delete and repost there.  Maybe @ToddTrimble would answer at the other site?  I hope we do not seem unwelcoming here, this is just not a "research level" question.  Hope to see more of your questions here in the future!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice question!  As user43208 says in comments, I presume you’re assuming $\newcommand{\CC}{\mathcal{C}}\CC$ is Cartesian closed throughout.

The most straightforward way to see this as a natural transformation is to consider $Y$ as fixed.  Then $Z^Y \times Y^X$ and $Z^X$ can each be seen as functors of two variables, contravariant in $X$ and covariant in $X$, i.e. as functors $\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}}\CC^\op \times \CC \to \CC$.

Slightly better is to see $Z^Y \times Y^X$ as “isovariant” in $Y$, i.e. see both as functors $\CC^\op \times \CC^{\mathrm{iso}} \times \CC \to \CC$.  (I’ll leave the details of this approach as an exercise.)

But best of all (again as user43208 says) is to move to the language of *dinatural* and *extranatural* transformations, which was designed exactly for this sort of situation, where you have a construction like $Z^Y \times Y^X$ which is covariant in some instances of an argument and contravariant in others. You can find full details [at the n-lab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extranatural+transformation), but roughly, the way this works is by splitting the co- and contra-variant instances of $Y$ into two different arguments, $Y_+$ and $Y_-$, and thinking about the functor of four variables $Z^{Y_-} \times Y_+^X : \CC^\op \times \CC \times \CC^\op \times \CC \to \CC$, and similarly thinking of $Z^X$ as a functor of those four variables (in which $Y_+$, $Y_-$ just so happen not to appear).  Then a *dinatural* transformation between these is a family of maps $\alpha_{X,Y,Z}$ between “diagonal instances” (i.e. instances where both $Y_+$, $Y_-$ are given the same value $Y$), satisfying a naturality condition saying that for any $X,Y_+, Y_-,Z$ and map $f : {Y_-} \to Y_+$, the two different ways of getting from $Z^{Y_-} \times Y_+^X$ to $Z^X$ are the same.

(Exercise: draw out this naturality diagram!  Hint: the “two different ways” go via $Z^{Y_+} \times {Y_+}^X$ and $Z^{Y_-} \times {Y_-}^X$ respectively.)

These three approaches take successively more language to set up; but they encapsulate increasingly more about the naturality of this composition operation.

Comment: I corrected something which I'm pretty sure was a typo, let me know if I introduced an error doing so.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: you were absolutely right, thanks for the typo fix!